# Build Unity from C# script

Tags: unity, deployment, automation, unity-webgl

I'd like to build and package all the ports of my Unity game through a scripting system. Linux and Windows work fine through the Unity command line options, but there is none for WebGL.

For WebGL, the only existing solution seems to be its `BuildPipeline`. There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jagwire/0129d50778c8b4462b68) with some sample code that has been referenced quit a few times. I changed its content to look like this:

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "./WebGL-Test", BuildTarget.WebGL, BuildOptions.None);
```

and call it with `unity-editor-beta -executeMethod WebGLBuilder.build`  (Btw, is there a way to call this method from within Unity? It doesn't help I have to restart Unity each time I want to test if the script works). It will fail with the following error:

```
Assets/Scripts/WebGLBuilder.cs(18,3): error CS0103: The name `BuildPipeline' does not exist in the current context
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
```

I also tried to use the `BuildPlayerOptions` class instead but no success. How do I get WebGL to build automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to an answer on [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/576746/build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor.html), you need to put the scripts used for building into a folder named `Editor` (specifically, `./Assets/Scripts/Editor`). Here's a full working build script:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

class BuildSrcipt
{
    static string[] scenes = { "Assets/Scenes/MyScene.unity" };
    static string name = "MyGame";

    [MenuItem("Build/Build WebGL")]
    static void BuildWebGL()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "./" + name + "_Web/" + name, BuildTarget.WebGL, BuildOptions.None);
    }

    [MenuItem("Build/Build Windows")]
    static void BuildWindows()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "./" + name + "_Windows/" + name, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64, BuildOptions.None);
    }

    [MenuItem("Build/Build Linux")]
    static void BuildLinux()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "./" + name + "_Linux/" + name, BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux64, BuildOptions.None);
    }

    [MenuItem("Build/Build All")]
    static void BuildAll()
    {
        BuildLinux();
        BuildWindows();
        BuildWebGL();
    }
}
```